# Samba Shares via Linux Client

Tags: networking, permissions, mount, samba

Network with Ubuntu 16x file server and Samba shares.  Windows 7 & 10 clients access the shares with Full permissions. Was able to mount share from Linux client (Mint 18.3).  Connects, but read only.

mounted as:
//192.168.x.x/public /home/public/Documents cifs rw,username=pubuser,password=xxxxxx 0 0

"pubuser" is the Linux and Samba account. The Windows clients connect (map) and have full permission to the share.

also tried mounting as:
////192.168.x.x/public /home/public/Documents cifs uid=1002,gid=1001,credentials=mnt/public/pubuser.cred 0 0

"pubuser.cred" is file with defined password.  I get the same results using this method (read only).

Appreciate any help. I've been using Samba here for 10+ years, but with Windows clients only.

Answer (score 0):

Your second fstab mount expression is a mess. Hopefully it's all a typo. It also begs a lot of questions: (1) who is uid=1002 and gid=1001. ( 2) What permissions does /home/public/Documents have and does it allow whoever uid=1002 or gid=1001 write access. (3) Does pubuser have a samba password or are you trying to access the share with it's local login password?

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to read/ask.  The syntax of the 2nd expression was one I found while searching the web.  pubuser (uid is 1002) has a Linux & Samba account, same password, "public" is group pubuser is in (gid is 1001), root user and public group own the directory shared on Linux server. The user on Linux client has full permissions to /home/public/Documents on local client.  The /mnt/public/pubuser.cred is a file containing the password.  Regardless of the 2 methods used above, both give read only access the Samba share.

Answer (score 0):

The way I read your last comment the uid / gid referenced is for the pubuser on the server. What is the uid of the user on the client. Run the following command to find out:

```
id
```

That is the uid you want to reference in the fstab declaration. So if the user on the client machine has a uid of say ... 1000 the correct syntax for your fstab declaration would be:

```
//192.168.x.x/public /home/public/Documents cifs uid=1000,credentials=/mnt/public/pubuser.cred 0 0
```